# couldn't add a dynamic router leading to a detail page React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of restaurants retreived from firestore and and I have to return the detail page of each one once clicking on the name of the restaurant. On page ProductGrid I ve returned all my restaurants already stored in firestore then from each name of restaurant I should go to ProductDetail which will contain the details of each restaurant(dynamic routing) I ve created the routes but no page is returned I can't figure out what is exactly the problem!! This is the link leading to the productDetail page

**ProductGrid.js**

`` <h2> <Link to={`ecom-product-detail/${data.id}`}>{data.data.name_restaurant}</Link> </h2> ``

**ProductDetail.js**

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { firestore } from "../../../../../fire";

function ProductDetail(){

   const {productId}= useParams();
   const thisProduct = firestore.collection("Restaurants").doc().get.find((prod) => prod.id === productId);

return(

  
      <div className="col-12">
      <div className="card">
            <h1>{thisProduct.name_restaurant}</h1>
            <p> Price:${thisProduct.Currency}</p>
            <p> {thisProduct.email}          </p>
      </div>
      </div>
   
      
    ) ; }
    export default ProductDetail;
```

**Routes.js**

```
    const Routes = () => {
    const routes = [
      { url: "ecom-product-detail/:productId", component: ProductDetail },
      ];
      return (
      <Fragment>
         <Switch>
            {routes.map((data, i) => (
               <Route
                  key={i}
                  exact
                  path={`/${data.url}`}
                  component={data.component}
               />
            ))}
         </Switch>

         {/* <Footer /> */}
      </Fragment>
   );
};

export default Routes;
```

**This is my Restaurants List retreived from firestore**

[image]

**This the page rendered when I click on the name of the restaurant**

[image]

Comment: what do you get if you copy the link location of the product?

Answer (score 0):

The code in the `ProductDetails` needs to handle async and state changes properly. I would recommend to refactor it to this:

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { firestore } from "../../../../../fire";

function ProductDetail() {
  const [thisProduct, setProduct] = useState({});
  const { productId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    firestore
      .collection("products")
      .doc(productId)
      .onSnapshot(function (doc) {
        setProduct(doc.data());
      });
  }, [productId]);

  return (
    <div className="col-12">
      <div className="card">
        <h1>{thisProduct.name_restaurant}</h1>
        <p> Price:${thisProduct.Currency}</p>
        <p> {thisProduct.email} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ProductDetail;
```

Comment: Thanks for interacting!! Unfortunately this didn't worked .Actually I think there is some issue in the link  used in ProductGrid to pass into ProductDetails :  <h2> <Link to={`ecom-product-detail/${data.id}`}>{data.data.name_restaurant}</Link> </h2>.Should I change anything here ?

Comment: No that's exactly the problem because even when I only return "Hello world" nothing was returned and same in the console That's why I thought the problem exists somewhere in the routing or in the link

Comment: Do you have a `Router` component above the `Switch` component?

Comment: No  I don't have

Comment: Pls put one above it. It kan't work without. Check for that the `react-router` docs. The basic examples should show how to do it.